# How to go into fastboot in realme device?

Tags: android, performance, root, rom, custom-rom

I tried to go into custom recovery but it is not going?

i have realme device which is realme 6 with heleo g90t. it is very difficult for me to go into recovery and i am stucked into fastboot

I think i'm doing wrong process for this...
can anyone have any solutions?